# as3 #1009 error code provided. "Null Object reference"

Tags: actionscript-3

hi I'm relatively new to as3 (this year) and I'm getting this error

> typer error #1009 cannot access a property or method of a null object
>   reference.    at FoodObject/collisionTest()

i was hoping anyone could help

```
package {
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.events.*
    import flash.utils.*
    import flash.display.Stage;

public class GameScene1 extends Scene {

    //public variables
    //character & scenery
    public var mainChar: Character;
    public var testFood: FoodObject;




    //constructor is used to create all necessary objects for this scene and display them
    public function GameScene1(gm_: Manager) {

        //constructor

        super(gm_);
        trace("GameScene 1 constructor");


        //character
        mainChar = new Character;
        addChild(mainChar);
        mainChar.x = 200;
        mainChar.y = 200;


        testFood = new FoodObject;
        addChild(testFood)
        testFood.x = 50
        testFood.y = 200
```

the food object class is here.

```
package  {
import GameScene1
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;


public class FoodObject extends MovieClip {
    public var Game1:GameScene1;

    public function FoodObject() {
         //constructor code
        this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, collisionTest)
    }

    public function collisionTest(e:Event)
    {
        if (this.hitTestObject(Game1.mainChar))
        {
            trace("it works")
        }
    }

}
```

}

game manager here:
    package  {

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;


public class Manager extends MovieClip {

    //stores which scene is currently loaded
    public var curScene:Scene=null;

    public function Manager() {
        //constructor
        trace("Manager Construct")
        GoToScene("menu");
    }


    public function GoToScene(name:String)
    {
        if (curScene) //there was a scene already
        {
        curScene.OnLeaveScene(); //call its OnLeaveScene function to remove all objects
        removeChild(curScene);
        }

        if(name=="menu") curScene = new MenuScene(this);
        if(name=="select") curScene = new SelectScene(this);
        if(name=="game1") curScene = new GameScene1(this);
        if(name=="game2") curScene = new GameScene2(this);
        if(name=="game3") curScene = new GameScene3(this);
        if(name=="credit") curScene = new CreditScene(this);

        addChild(curScene);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that the concerns of your classes are not separate:

Your `Scene` knows both the `Character` and the `Food` object, you instantiate both classes there, nothing wrong with that.

The problem starts when you are trying to do something in the `Food` object, that requires knowledge of the character. The thing is: the `Food` object doesn't know anything about the `Character`.

You can solve this by simply passing the reference of `Character` to your `Food` object. In order to do this, modify the constructor like so:

```
private var character:Character;
public function FoodObject(character:Character) {
     //constructor code
    this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, collisionTest)
    this.character = character;
}
```

The usage of said constructor in your `Scene` changes as follows:

```
testFood = new FoodObject(mainCharacter);
```

This way, `Food` knows the character and can do stuff with it, for example do collision tests:

```
   public function collisionTest(e:Event)
    {
        if (this.hitTestObject(character)) // ==== this line changed
        {
            trace("it works")
        }
    }
```

---

However, this raises an important issue: **Why should `Food` know the `Character` at all?**

Sure enough, you want to do the collision test, which **requires both objects**.
But why do you want to do it in the `Food` object?

Doing the collision check in `Food` is cumbersome, because you have to pass a reference to `Character` in order to do it there.

**The much preferred way** of doing this is to **do the collision check where both objects participating in the check are already known**.
In your case, this is the `Scene`.

Think about how easy it is to do the check in `Scene`:

```
testFood.hitTestObject(mainCharacter);
```

It's that simple, because everything you need is already there.

---

To recap:

- The collision check requires knowledge of 2 objects that you want to
  check.
- In order to do the check in either one, you have to pass a reference
  of the other. (`Character` to `Food` as seen above or the other way
  round)
- It is a lot easier to do the check in some place that already knows
  both objects, because no reference have to be passed around.

Your original code failed because `Game1` in `FoodObject` is never assigned a value and therefore remains `null`.
Invoking methods on `null` causes the error you experienced.

Comment: The irony of @null answering questions about 1009 errors...haha.   Good answer though.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to take the instance of GameScene1 class using `new` keyword.

```
public var Game1:GameScene1;

public function FoodObject() {
     //constructor code
     var _manager:Manager = new Manager();
     Game1 = new GameScene1(_manager)
    this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, collisionTest);
}

public function collisionTest(e:Event):void{
    ....
}
```

Comment: doing so creates an endless loop of GameScene1

Comment: i dont know why, but GameScene1's keep being created, i have a trace each time one is. I think it is because food object is calling GameScene1 through the new keyword but GameScene1 is creating foodObjects in the constructor so it keeps repeating