# AS3 - Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference on gotoAndPlay

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a scene that contains a movie clip. That movie clip has a button that controls the y position of a symbol in the scene. What I tried to do is move on to the next scene when the symbol reaches certain y values. I used **gotoAndPlay** when the desired y position was reached, the new scene was switched to but an error appeared on output as indicated by the title. This is the code that appears in the movie clip:

```
launch_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, init_launch)

function init_launch(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    MovieClip(root).launch_video.play();
    var k = setTimeout(launch, 1);
}

function launch():void
{
    trace(MovieClip(root).rkt.y);

    if(MovieClip(root).rkt.y != null)
    {
        //progressively changing the y position
        if(MovieClip(root).rkt.y != null)
        {
            if(MovieClip(root).rkt.y < 600)
            {
                MovieClip(root).rkt.y -=0.3
            }
            if(MovieClip(root).rkt.y < 500)
            {
                 ...
            }
            setTimeout(launch, 1);

            if(MovieClip(root).rkt.y < -150)
            {
                MovieClip(root).gotoAndPlay(1, "Scene 3")
            }
    }
}
```

Currently, as compile this code the error points to the line "trace(MovieClip(root).rkt.y);".

What I don't get is why **rkt** suddenly becomes null when I try to go to a different scene. I tried checking if the property is null but that doesn't help.

I tried removing **eventListener**, and calling functions that resided in the actions layer of the scene itself (the original one) instead of directly going to the scene from the movie clip.

All in vain.

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [as3 #1009 error code provided. "Null Object reference"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29630538/as3-1009-error-code-provided-null-object-reference)

Answer (score 1):

> What I don't get is why rkt suddenly becomes null when I try to go to a different scene. I tried checking if the property is null but that doesn't help.

It's the object that's `null`, not the property.

> I tried removing eventListener

Which won't help much given that the continuing calls to `launch` are not triggered by an event but `setTimeout` which will keep firing.

Stop using `setTimeout` and use a `Timer`. This allows you to remove the event listeners properly and actually stop it.

Answer (score -1):

**MovieClip(root)** was actually the property that turned null when the y position was reached. I modified the condition inside **launch()** to handle that:

```
 function launch():void
 {
    if(MovieClip(root)!= null)
    {
        rest of code...
    }
 }
```

I really hope this would help others. I only posted a question here after much research online and particularly here. It appears this error plagues a lot of developers.

Comment: Great to see that you found the reason for your problem yourself. The solution is however not really good. The function is still being called continuously and your if statement merely prevents the error. But the function should **not** be called any more in the first place.

Comment: Hi null, I implemented the Timer instead of setTimeout. It works but I still get the same error if I remove the if statement. The question is, should I keep the if statement in place? Unless I didn't implement the Timer properly.

Comment: Are you stopping the `Timer`? Are you removing the listeners added to it?

Comment: Your're right! I did everything except stopping the timer. Many thanks @null, much appreciated!